# Como definir alternadamente a cor de background de sections de uma página com CSS?

Tags: css

Dentro do **body** do meu documento HTML tenho uma sequência de 5 sections, esse número pode variar dependendo da situação.

Gostaria de definir um destaque (background) diferente para cada section **"*par*"**, ou seja, pular 1 section e aplicar um background-color, pular outra e aplicar novamente o mesmo estilo, sucessivas vezes até a ultima section da página.

Answer (score 2):

Existem seletores especificos para apanhar os elementos pares e impares, que permitem fazer o que quer com facilidade.

Pode começar por formatar todos os elementos normalmente e sobrepõe a formatação para os pares com o seletor:

```
section:nth-child(even)
```

Ou para os impares com:

```
section:nth-child(odd)
```

Exemplo:

```css
section {
  background-color:lightBlue;
  height:80px;
}

section:nth-child(even){ /*pares com fundo azul*/
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

[Documentação para o `nth-child` no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)

Answer (score 2):

Usando `:nth-child(even)` ou `:nth-of-type(even)`, você pode facilmente obter o resultado desejado. Ele vai selecionar todos que foram "even", ou seja, todos os pares.

Observe esse exemplo em http://cssdeck.com/labs/rib8dumb:

```css
/* Propósito Estético */
section {
  color: white;
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
}

/* Pares */
section:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ccc;
}

/* Impares */
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333
}
```

```html
<section>Section #1</section>
<section>Section #2</section>
<section>Section #3</section>
<section>Section #4</section>
<section>Section #5</section>
```

Lembrando que existem mil e uma maneiras de usar essas pseudo-classes. Esse site lista quase todas as maneiras que você pode usar: http://nthmaster.com